# segmentation fault in C project

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This is a piece of code for a school project i'm working on.

```
typedef struct Location{
    int x;
    int y;
   int hasTreasure;
}Location; 

typedef   struct Location *PtrLocation;


PtrLocation createLocation(int x,int y){
    PtrLocation ptrLocation;
    if(ptrLocation= malloc(sizeof(struct Location)) == NULL) return NO_MEM;

    ptrLocation->x=x;  // place where the segmentation fault occurs
    ptrLocation->y=y;
    ptrLocation->hasTreasure=0;

    return ptrLocation;
}
```

whenever i try to run the following lines in main:

```
PtrLocation location;
location = createLocation(5,5);
```

my program gives me a segmentation fault error

a friend of mine did the exact same thing on his project and it seems like it's working. We are using the CodeBlocks IDE with the GNU GCC compiler

EDIT: i forgot some lines, my bad.

Comment: Are you sure this function is where the segmentation fault occurs?  A line number might help us for sure.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info; `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Then use the debugger (`gdb`) & `valgrind`

Comment: @MichaelDorgan the segmentation fault occurs in this line:              ptrLocation->x=x;

Comment: Try enclosing `ptrLocation= malloc(sizeof(struct Location))` in parenthesis like `(ptrLocation= malloc(sizeof(struct Location)))`

Comment: @Fjotten you are a god

Comment: @Fjotten and i'm really, really stupid

Comment: Note that @BasileStarynkevitch actually had the first correct response as turning on warnings would have pointed this out immediatetly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a parenthesis in your if statement.
It should be :

```
if((ptrLocation = malloc(sizeof(struct Location))) == NULL) return NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I dropped the following into codepad as a test and it ran without issue.

```
typedef struct Location{
    int x;
    int y;
    int hasTreasure;
}Location; 

typedef   struct Location *PtrLocation;


PtrLocation createLocation(int x,int y){
    PtrLocation ptrLocation;
    if((ptrLocation= malloc(sizeof(struct Location))) == NULL) return NULL;

    ptrLocation->x=x;
    ptrLocation->y=y;
    ptrLocation->hasTreasure=0;

    return ptrLocation;
}

int main(void)
{
    PtrLocation location;
    location = createLocation(5,5);

    return 0;
}
```

Perhaps you are calling your createLocation a bazillion times?  Or perhaps somewhere else in your code, you have overwritten your heap, which manifests as a bad malloc call?  I'd consider looking at the rest of your code as the code supplied, save for the parenthesis order, is fine.

---

Just realized what the issue may be

Because of your missing parenthesis in the if, there is a good chance malloc is never being called which could lead to the seg-fault.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
PtrLocation ptrLocation = malloc(sizeof(Location));
if(ptrLocation == NULL) return NO_MEM;
```

instead of:

```
PtrLocation ptrLocation;
if(ptrLocation= malloc(sizeof(struct Location)) == NULL) return NO_MEM;
```

Something is going on with trying to set the value of ptrLocation in the if block that isn't working; I was able to avoid a segfault in this manner. Assignment happens last, so if you are going to put it in the if block, you will need to put the whole assignment statement in parenthesis, like this:

```
if((ptrLocation= malloc(sizeof(struct Location))) == NULL) return NO_MEM;
```

*note: The precedence of assignment is 14 while the precedence of comparison is 7. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 0):

The program seems correct at the first time. However there is a minute error in line that calls the malloc function.

Note that the below code is a declaration of a pointer to the structure.

```
typedef   struct Location *PtrLocation;
```

A pointer has a memory allocation of 4 bytes in modern compilers, however the structure as a whole is having higher size. Thus on malloc there is a segmentation fault which is due to wrong initialization. Malloc is making cast from integer variable in the "PtrLocation" to the "struct Location"

There is this difference in the space which is causing the segmentation fault.